# Pushing "undefined" on an array consumes tons of memory?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, memory, undefined

I have this bizarre bug that's eating up tons of memory and keeps causing my server to crash.

Every 30 seconds I save a value to an array:

```
historicalValues.push( valueToSave )
```

When valueToSave = 1, the app doesn't have any large increase in memory from this.

But when valueToSave = undefined or null, the app suddenly increases 90 MB in 2 minutes??

Anybody know what could be causing this? I'm pretty sure a null variable doesn't take up massively more memory than a number. Does it have something to do with that it forces the array to have to switch to a less efficient object type to be able to support entries of multiple different types of objects? Thought javascript didn't care about stuff like that.

Comment: `it forces the array to have to switch to a less efficient object type to be able to support entries of multiple different types of objects? Thought javascript didn't care about stuff like that.` You'd be surprised: https://v8project.blogspot.com.au/2017/09/elements-kinds-in-v8.html

Comment: Does the memory consumption *keep* increasing at that rate, or is it a one-time thing?

Comment: What makes you think the memory increase in 2 minutes is coming from 4 array push operations? If you check and replace undefined or null with 1, does the memory increase not happen?

Comment: Why would a server crash from using 90 mb?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are mixing types at the Array, it increases the memory regardless if it's `undefined`, `null` or whatever. That's because you are facing that.

If you don't need these values just filter them before pushing them.

If you indeed need these values just transform to integer these values.

If you have an array of integers but also need to use `undefined` and `null` as possible values, please check for them before pushing and if they are `undefined` or `null` push the integer 0.

Since `undefined` and `null` evaluate to false you could reach it as follow:

```
if(!value) {
   array.push(0)
} else {
   array.push(value)
}

[12,20,30,0,32,0,0,5]
```